# Distribution of residuals envelops normal distribution

Tags: distributions, data-visualization, stata, residuals, diagnostic

when plotting the distribution of the obtained residuals (from a regression) in stata to see if they fit a normal distribution, I get following result:
[image: residual distribution]

This seemed very odd to me at first but when I investigated it further, I found following reasons for this behavior:

1) The dependent variable can only take on the values 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 and 7

2) all fitted valaues lie between 3.6 and 4.2

So naturally, some values of residuals can't ever exist, namely all values with .5-.7. My question is, what kind of implications does this have when assessing normality? Other than the up and downs of the distribution, it does seem to follow a normal distribution. But can I assume that residuals are normally distributed based on this?

Comment: Do you mean the *dependent* variable can only take on certain values?

Comment: All normally distributed variables take values on the range $(-\infty,\infty)$ and are continuous (though there's more to them than that of course).

If your distribution is bounded in the values it can take, it is plainly not normal.

If the values taken by your response are small positive integers, they are plainly not normal. If the original response variable is discrete, then the conditional distributions are all discrete; it is the conditional distributions that are assumed normal if you make a normality assumption in regression.  ... ctd

Comment: ctd... Since it's clear before we even get data that it cannot possibly be actually normal, we must ask ourselves what is the purpose of the assessment? You presumably want to answer a different question than "is this variable normal" -- the answer to that question would almost never be yes.

A more useful question might be "is the situation I am in one where the non-normality I have is not going to affect my tests/confidence intervals etc more than I am prepared to accept?" ... and a hypothesis test won't address that. (This is addressed many times on site.)

Answer (score 1):

> All normally distributed variables take values on the range (−∞,∞) and
>   are continuous (though there's more to them than that of course). If
>   your distribution is bounded in the values it can take, it is plainly
>   not normal. If the values taken by your response are small positive
>   integers, they are plainly not normal. If the original response
>   variable is discrete, then the conditional distributions are all
>   discrete; it is the conditional distributions that are assumed normal
>   if you make a normality assumption in regression.
>
> Since it's clear before we even get data that it cannot possibly be
>   actually normal, we must ask ourselves what is the purpose of the
>   assessment? You presumably want to answer a different question than
>   "is this variable normal" -- the answer to that question would almost
>   never be yes. A more useful question might be "is the situation I am
>   in one where the non-normality I have is not going to affect my
>   tests/confidence intervals etc more than I am prepared to accept?" ...
>   and a hypothesis test won't address that. (This is addressed many
>   times on site.)

-Glen_b

Comment: I've copied this comment by Glen_b as a community wiki answer because the comment is, more or less, an answer to this question. We have a dramatic gap between answers and questions. At least part of the problem is that some questions are answered in comments: if comments which answered the question were answers instead, we would have fewer unanswered questions.